# There is an instance of anaconda navigator already running error

Tags: python-3.x, windows, anaconda, conda

Previously my anaconda navigator was not responding so I have rebooted my computer and now when I am trying to open anaconda navigator it pop-ups an error with "there is an instance of anaconda navigator already running".

OS: Windows 10

[image: This is a message on pop up window]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I met the same problem a few days ago. I found the anaconda navigator will start a process called `pythonw`. So the following is my solution:

1. open a cmd window;
2. use command `tasklist | findstr "pythonw"` to find the pid of pythonw, like 37200;
3. use command `tskill 37200` to kill the process.

By the way, my OS is Windows.

Comment: I got "End process failed for 37200: No access". Any suggestions?

Comment: Check the port number it is showing on your command prompt. Use that instead of 37200.

Answer (score 38):

I got the same error in MAC. logoff & login did not resolve the issue and the below command solved my issue in mac. Restart not required.

```
killall python
```

Answer (score 8):

[With images] The instructions Below works flawlessly in Windows 10.

1. Run `CMD` (command prompt) with **administrator** privileges
2. Run the following command,

```
tasklist | findstr "pythonw"
```

3. Lastly, after identifying process ID run this command to kill the process,

```
taskkill /f /pid <PID NUMBER>
```

Happy Learning :):)

[image: Snap of CMD in Windows 10]

Answer (score 6):

1.In anaconda prompt

```
 $ anaconda-navigator --reset
 $ anaconda-navigator
```

Answer (score 5):

one of the following will solve your issue in ubuntu:

```
killall Anaconda-Navigator 

anaconda-navigator --reset
```

Answer (score 1):

The following steps worked for me in windows.
You can do the following.

1. `tasklist | findstr "pythonw"`
   The PID of the processes will get displayed.
2. `taskkill /pid "PID" (without quotes) /f`

This will successfully kill the Anaconda Navigator task.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem on windows 10, and all the previous answers and commands to **taskkill didn't work** and gave me the error **"Access denied"**.

I found out that when you turn off your computer in windows 10, by default it doesn't really turn off but instead it hibernates, so it doesn't really "kill" all the tasks running.

**Therefore my solution:**

1. Go to Windows Start Menu, select _Settings  > System > Power & sleep > Additional power settings > Chose what the power button does.
2. Under Power button settings, tap the setting bar, choose the option "Shut down".
3. Click on "Change settings that are currently unavailable", and uncheck the "Turn on fast startup" box.
4. Click on save changes.
5. Now **Restart** your computer.

This will successfully kill all running tasks, including `pythonw`, and hopefully solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can use either of below options to resolve the issue.

```
1. tasklist | findstr "pythonw"
   tskill <pid>
2. Also we can End the task names 'Python' from Task Manager.
```

Now open the Anaconda Navigator again. It may take a while to open.

Answer (score 0):

I used these processes and it solved my problem :)
open task manager > click processes on the menu > click on "pythonw" > click End process
is may solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

For those who killed the Python processes but the GUI still doesn't show, for me the .condarc file was missing in my user folder...  so  I created the .condarc file and left it blank, killed the python process, then relaunched and it worked.

My issue was after installing for the first time

Answer (score 0):

I loaded Process Hacker software on Windows 10 and in this software, I search for pythons.exe process, right click and select Terminate. This software is freeware. I am trying to help those who don’t want to type dos command.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem. This worked for me.
Open CMD and Find the tasks using
tasklist | findstr "pythonw"
Try to kill the tasks using
taskkill /pid "processid" /f
(Processid is the id u got from tasklist)
Switch off wifi and try to open anaconda navigator

Comment: Please don't duplicate other answers in similar words.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the step you can use to solve this issue quickly.

1. Open Task Manager or use shortcut key `Ctrl+Shift+Esc`.
2. Find `Python` process in the list.
3. Kill those processes by clicking on it and click `End task`.

Then open Anaconda Navigator again.