# Unable to open anaconda navigator

Tags: anaconda

When I open the Anaconda Navigator I get this message 'there is an instance of anaconda navigator already running', like in this question [There is an instance of anaconda navigator already running error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50079641/there-is-an-instance-of-anaconda-navigator-already-running-error), but the answer doesnt't fix my problem. How can I do?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

```
anaconda-navigator --reset
spyder --reset
```

to see the reffence
https://vcodery.com/there-is-an-instance-of-anaconda-navigator-already-running-error/

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Sorry. I mean that you can type these commands in your terminal to reset your navigator and spyder(if you want to use it)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Anaconda and reinstall with the option "Just Me" instead of "All Users"